# Nuxt Content Filtering on an object

Tags: nuxt.js, nuxt-content

having a bit of an issue wrapping my head around how to do Nuxt Content where() on objects. What I mean by that is consider the following url:

```
www.mysite.com/blog/tag/tag-slug-here
```

On this page I need to filter all the articles by that tag slug. Now my .md structure is as follows:

```
---
layout: documentation
title: Post Title
date: 2016-06-14T15:24:30.719Z
date_updated: ''
tags:
  - retainer
  - clients
---

...
```

Now I did notice in the following:

> In order to filter in objects and array you need to enable nestedProperties, see [configuration](https://content.nuxtjs.org/configuration#nestedproperties).

So in my nuxt config I added:

```
  content: {
    nestedProperties: ['tags']
  },
```

However this didn't seem to work either.

My Search Code:

```
const articles = await $content()
      .where({ tags: params.slug })
      .only(['title', 'description', 'thumbnail', 'slug', 'author', 'date'])
      .sortBy('date', 'desc')
      .limit(5)
      .skip((route.query.page || 1) * 5)
      .fetch()
```

I'm not sure if i'm misunderstanding the docs or the search but if anyone has any ideas that would be amazing!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found my answer:
https://github.com/nuxtlabs/demo-blog-nuxt-content/blob/master/pages/blog/tag/_tag.vue

This file is a great example of how to do tag searching.